# Script to configure install variables and output correct install switches

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I need help with a script that will pull the hostname or username of a user logged in a windows computer and compare it against a table of hostnames or usernames and add the right variable.
EX.

```
computer1=Phone1
computer2=phone2
computer3=phone3

using this table i have to change a variable 

msiexec /i programtoinstall /qb FREEFORMDEVICENAME="using the host name or username get the right variable"
```

so ..if the hostname was computer1  then the finial install string should be:

```
msiexec /i programtoinstall /qb FREEFORMDEVICENAME="phone1"
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the table is like your example in a plain text file called `file.table` then this should work:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in (file.table) do (
if /i "%%a"=="%computername%" msiexec /i programtoinstall /qb FREEFORMDEVICENAME="%%b"
)
```

Comment: Thanks!  What needs to be put if its the username and not the hostname?

Comment: `"%username%"` instead of `"%computername%"`